# Passing blocknumber to eth.contract.method.balanceOf

Tags: web3js, contract-development

I read that there is an option to pass blocknumber to contract.methods.balanceOf
I am currently passing it like this:

```
const address ='0x6C1F09F6271fbE133Db38DB9c9280307F5d22160';
  contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call((error, balance) => {
    contract.methods.decimals().call((error, decimals) => {
    //   balance = balance.div(10 ** decimals);
      console.log(balance);
    });
  });
```

Any ideas how to pass the blocknumber into this?

Comment: And I think I told you that on a different post (though it might have been someone else's post) - don't do `10 ** decimals`, because it most likely exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. You can instead use `1e${decimals}` encapsulated with a pair of ` , but I'm not entirely sure about the type of `balance`, so `div` might disallow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
call((error, balance) => {
```

To this:

```
call(null, blockNumber, (error, balance) => {
```